# Laptop mic doesn't pickup sound. Though it shows audio level when I knock with finger

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I have Acer Asipre 7745G. Using Windows 10. I easily can get max mic audio level by knocking with my finger to the mic but if I run mic tests, I can't hear any sound on speakers. Any solution for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What software are you using to do the mic test? Typically, these issues occur because that software had a noise reduction option that's been turned on and is overdoing its job. I find that this is particularly common for Discord mic tests.

Comment: I use Chrome, I usually need BigBlueButton for lectures, but I tried a lot of tests and it non of them work. Would like to know how to disable it in Chrome.

Comment: Tried to add `--enable-blink-features=DisableHardwareNoiseSuppression` flag, but there is no difference.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that on Firefox mic tests works well.

Comment: @Pranciskus So everything works perfectly on Firefox?

Comment: Well, a lot of noise, but at least I can hear myself.

Answer (score 2):

The microphone is picking up sound, and the PC is processing the signal, but, *by default*, the PC does not pass that signal to the speaker. This is done to prevent feedback, the squeal heard when you put two connected phones together.

However, if you're using *headphones*, and want to hear your voice to monitor it, [you can send sound from the mic to the speaker/headphone jack](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/output-mic-sound-to-speakers-windows-10/):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *mmsys.cpl* to open the *Sound Control Panel*.
- On the *Playback* tab, right-click the correct speaker or headphone and set it as the default device.

[image: Set default speaker]

- On the *Recording* tab, right-click the correct microphone and set it as the default device.

[image: Set default microphone]

- With the microphone selected, right-click and select *Properties*.
- On the *Listen* tab of the *Microphone Properties* dialog, set *Listen to this device*.

[image: Set listen to microphone]

Of course, expect feedback if the output is going to nearby loudspeakers.

Comment: Thank you, I can hear my mic using "Listen to this device". There is a lot of computer noise, but at least I hear myself.